# Redirect if Wordpress query string is empty

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I've added a query string to my Wordpress installation using the following code in my `functions.php` file:

```
function add_query_vars($aVars) {
    $aVars[] = "username";
    return $aVars;
}

add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');

function add_rewrite_rules($aRules) {
    $aNewRules = array(
        '([^/]+)/manage' => 'index.php?pagename=manage&username=$matches[1]',
        '([^/]+)/settings' => 'index.php?pagename=settings&username=$matches[1]',
    );
    $aRules = $aNewRules + $aRules;
    return $aRules;
}

add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules');
```

However, I don't want to load the page template if the `username` query string is empty, rather I'd like to redirect to the homepage.  For instance:

```
website.com/myusername/manage
```

... would load a page template

```
website.com/manage
```

... would redirect home.

Can I do this using Wordpress' rewrite engine or should I take another approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I would use this code:

```
function redirect_to_homepage( $query ) {   
    //page manage and settings does NOT exits
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && ( $query->query_vars['name'] == 'manage' || $query->query_vars['name'] == 'settings' ) ){       
        if( ( !array_key_exists( 'username', $query->query_vars ) || ( array_key_exists( 'username', $query->query_vars ) && trim($query->query_vars['username']) == '' ) ) ) {
            wp_redirect( get_bloginfo('url') );
            exit;
        }   
    }
    //page manage and settings does exits
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && ( $query->is_page('manage') || $query->is_page('settings') ) ){
        if( ( !array_key_exists( 'username', $query->query_vars ) || ( array_key_exists( 'username', $query->query_vars ) && trim($query->query_vars['username']) == '' ) ) ) {
            wp_redirect( get_bloginfo('url') );
            exit;
        }   
    }
}
add_action( 'parse_query', 'redirect_to_homepage' );
```

Comment: Technically, you don't need everything you typed.  The following code will work: http://pastebin.com/rWSq7zSv

Comment: Your're right, but I did't know whether you've got a page manage and settings created in your backend or not. That's why I've put the code in full length...

Comment: Good call David, nice thinking!